# Check if key exists in map

Tags: javascript

I read that to check if a key exists in a ***Map*** , we can use the ***has*** method
I am using the following example:

```js
var mp = new Map();
mp["abc-def"] = 123;
if (mp.has("abc-def")) {
  console.log("found");
} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

Any suggestion on why the ***has*** method is not working here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To set key in map you need to use `set`

```js
var mp = new Map();
mp.set("abc-def", 123)
if (mp.has("abc-def")) {
  console.log("found");
} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

If you set property using `.` or `[]` it is still accessible because but not with the `has` function, because `Map` is also an object and similar to any other object you can add properties and access

```js
var mp = new Map();
mp["abc-def"] = 123;
if (mp.hasOwnProperty("abc-def")) {
  console.log("found");
} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

The reason for value not appearing with `has` but appearing with `[]` or `.` operator is there's `set` method set's value on `internal slot` and `has` method read it from `internal slot` [`DOCS Ref`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.set)

Comment: `mp["abc-def"]` checks for the value of the key `abc-def` not for the key. should be using `hasOwnProperty`. I haven't downvoted though.

Comment: @AZ_ yeah valid point, just updated, though the downvote was before this part is added to answer :p

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Map.prototype.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) to add or update an element with a specified key and a value to a Map object.

```js
var mp = new Map();
mp.set("abc-def", 123);
if(mp.has("abc-def"))
{
  console.log("found");
}
else{
  console.log("not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set)
You should use `set` for that

> Map.prototype.set(key, value)
>   Sets the value for the key in the Map object. Returns the Map object.

```
var map = new Map();
map.set("abc-def", 123)
if (map.has("abc-def")) {
console.log("key found");
} else {
console.log("key not found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mp["abc-def"] = 123;` try to set using [.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) method like `mp.set("abc-def", 123)` and for checking whether the key is existing of not you can use [.has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) like this

```
if (mp.has("abc-def")) {
  console.log("found");
} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```